# Mysql - Linux : Insert a record in a table at a specific date and time

Tags: mysql, linux, cron

I need to insert into a MySql table a record each year on 31st December 11:59pm.

The MySql database is stored in Ubuntu system.
I don't know if it can be done directly in MySql or if I need to create a shell script in Ubuntu.

If anyone has an idea about this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use scheduler for that:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Simple scheduler event:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' YEAR
STARTS '2015-12-31 23:59:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 -- insert your stuff
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I think you have to enable it by setting `event_scheduler` to  `ON`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an event - [CREATE EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html).
Set interval - YEAR, and set data and time when to start.

Answer (score 1):

1. Best you can do with **MySQL** is to use a Trigger if you want to
   insert the data on some event in DB.
2. You can do it programmatically by using some scheduler framework
       like **Quartz** which would call your insert DAO method.
3. And the simplest of all would be to have a script with **Cron
       job/script** in place which directly connects to your DB and inserts
       the data in specified time interval.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, starting from MySQL 5.1 we are provided event scheduling.

So, given your_db is usable, you could do:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS your_db;

USE your_db;

CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `ev` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ev`)
);

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

CREATE EVENT your_event ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2014-08-20 00:10:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
  INSERT INTO your_db.some_table (ev) VALUES (CONCAT_WS(' ', 'En Event Occurred at', NOW()));
```

To schedule a simple event occurring every 1 minute.

if it works (it does on my ubuntu 14.04 box), then I guess you'd just customize this snippet. You can change 'MINUTE' to 'YEAR'.

If it doesn't , please let us know.

For your reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

BTW: I'd rather not stick to a crontab script... in order to configure crontab you are required different set of privileges that those required for accessing mysql. Even so, it might still be a good choice in some occasions.